# Is there a library in python which is equivalent to Net::BGP library in perl?

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a library available in python which is equivalent to Net::BGP library in perl.

Please refer to this link for details about Net::BGP library.

http://search.cpan.org/~sscheck/Net-BGP-0.16/lib/Net/BGP.pm

Thanks,
Manoj Kumar V

Answer (score 1):

you can maybe find your happiness with the library yabgp :

YABGP is a yet another Python implementation for BGP Protocol. 
It can be used to establish BGP connections with all kinds of routers (include real Cisco/HuaWei/Juniper routers and some router simulators like GNS3) and receive/parse BGP messages for future analysis.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yabgp/0.2.6

good luck

Comment: Thanks you it works fine!